# Pillow ImageGrab.grabclipboard() crash after copying from wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I observe something odd and am wondering if I am doing anything wrong and/or if you experience the same as I do. If I copy some text from a wx.TextCtrl to the clipboard and then try to read an image from the clipboard using ImageGrab.grabclipboard(), my application hangs.

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.9, Pillow 10.0.0

I first observed this with Pillow 9.5.0, then upgraded to see if that made a difference: it doesn't.

Here is minimal code example. To use it, type some text in the wx.TextCtrl. Highlight the text and copy it to the clipboard. Then click the button.

```
import wx
from PIL import ImageGrab

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title="My Frame")

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Grab image")

        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_click)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def on_click(self, event):
        try:
            img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            print('Image grabbed from clipboard')
        except:
            print('No image found on clipboard')

app = wx.App()
MyFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

If you copy some text to the clipboard from outside the application and click the button, it will happily print 'No image found on clipboard'.

Comment: Try printing out the exception. On my Linux box it says `ImageGrab.grabclipboard() is macOS and Windows only`. I don't think it's been rewritten lately.

Comment: Not sure how to print the exception. When the only thing in **on_click** is ```img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()```, then nothing at all is printed on the console. It just hangs.

Comment: `except Exception as e:` then `print (str(e))`

Comment: Nothing happens. When I have some text on the clipboard prior to starting the program and immediately click the button, the output is ```xclip error: Error: target image/png not available```
```No image found on clipboard```

When I type something in the textctrl, copy it to the clipboard and then click the button, there is no output on the CLI.